# How to change the position of the volume up/down/mute notification popup?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, notify-osd

[image]

Well i really don't know how is it called but i'd like to know if i can change the position where it shows (top right corner), since i no longer have GNOME panels anywhere i don`t like that popup being there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PATCHED NOTIFYOSD UPDATES: OPTION TO PLACE THE NOTIFICATIONS IN DIFFERENT SCREEN CORNERS, TIMEOUT FIX

**install NotifyOSD**

```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Then restart it**

```
     pkill notify-osd
```

Now, to place the notification bubbles in a different screen corner, use the following command in a terminal:

```
     gconftool-2 -s /apps/notify-osd/gravity --type=int [number]
```

where is [number] can be:
1 - top-right corner
2 - middle-right
3 - bottom-right corner
4 - bottom-left corner
5 - middle-left
6 - top-left corner

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/patched-notifyosd-updates-option-to.html)

Comment: this is more or less what i wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

NotifyOSD Config is your solution :) You can read up more here:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/customize-the-ubuntu-notification-bubbles/

Comment: nope, tried it, i can change the size, and the color but not the position of it

Comment: while i can't move it to where I want, it rather moves it to a random position which is not exactly what i want to do

Comment: Sad to hear that :< I never had the need to move the notifications, perhaps somebody will have a better answer! :)

Comment: Actually you can change the position up to 1000px horizontally/vertically: sadly enough I found that this solution will not fit my need of moving the osd-notify bubbles on my primary monitor...